# Adding data value labels at both ends of the line graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, linegraph

I want to illustrate the changes in number of chinese lawyers from 2017 to 2021. I was successful in doing that. But I want to add data value labels at the ends of the line graph to illustrate before and after.

Here's the code :

```
category<-total_lawyers|>
              pivot_longer(cols =2:6, names_to = "year", values_to = "total" )
```

## graph

```
    category|>
  ggplot(aes(year, total, group=category,color=category))+
  geom_line(size=1.5)+scale_y_log10()+
  theme_stata()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())[
```

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuSIS.png)

what I want is to add to add data labels only at both ends.

Comment: There is a couple options you have for this. If you copy/paste the output of `dput(total_lawyers)` into your question everyone could have a reproducible data set. In general you can use the `annotate()` function to place arbitrary text/points/etc on your plot at specific locations. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Besides doing manual annotations as in the comment you can filter your data to just the data you want to highlight and then let ggplot do all the aesthetic mapping for you. Here is an example using the built in `mtcars` dataset. The dataset is filtered to obtain the minimum or maximum of the value plotted on the x-axis and then those points plotted with an additional geom using that filtered data set:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data_to_highlight <-
  mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl) |>
  filter(disp == min(disp) | disp == max(disp))

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = mtcars,
            aes(x = disp,
                y = mpg,
                color = as.factor(cyl)))+
  geom_point(data = data_to_highlight,
             aes(x = disp,
                 y = mpg,
                 color = as.factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

Note: You also can map the values as text and do some more fun stuff. Here the min/max points of the `disp` variable is highlighted with points and the corresponding `mpg` values written in text:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = mtcars,
            aes(x = disp,
                y = mpg,
                color = as.factor(cyl)))+
  geom_point(data = data_to_highlight,
             aes(x = disp,
                 y = mpg,
                 color = as.factor(cyl)),
             size = 6, shape = 16)+
  geom_text(data = data_to_highlight,
            aes(x = disp,
                y  = mpg,
                label = mpg),
            size = 2,
            color = "white")
```

[image]